# Unbind skin in Autodesk Maya

Tags: python, maya

Despite following the Maya command documentation shown [here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/bindSkin.html):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.bindSkin( unbind=True ) # While my object is selected.
```

or

```
cmds.bindSkin( 'mySelectedObj', unbind=True ) # Specifying which object to unbind
```

results in:

> Error: RuntimeError: file  line 1: No skin partition
>   found in scene.

I'm also getting the same error in MEL. But the script editor's history shows a `doDetachSkin` command - and searching on it just keeps leading me back to the bind skin command.

How should I correctly write this command when following the example on the documentation is giving me the error message?

P.S.: My selection is a geo mesh that is skinned to a few joints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> import maya.mel as mel
>
> skinC = mel.eval('doDetachSkin "2" { "1","1" }')

Decided to work around the issue instead by just invoking the mel command that I see in the script editor history. Not ideal but serves my purposes for now.

If anyone knows of a better way or can clue in why following the documentation isn't working, please feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with selection ?

```
mySelectedObj = cmds.ls(sl=True) or []
if mySelectedObj:
    cmds.bindSkin(mySelectedObj[0], unbind=True )
```

Comment: yes. I have. and I'm getting the exact same error message. The strange thing is - when I manually use the unbind command from the UI, it's working normally, but the script editor shows a "doDetachSkin" mel command that I can't find in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If `Unbind Skin` Python command doesn't work:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.bindSkin( unbind=True, bp=False )
```

Try its great old MEL equivalent:

```
DetachSkin;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bindSkin can only delete the jointCluster, and you can try skinCluster.

```
import pymel.core as pm
pm.skinCluster(objname, edit=True, unbind=True)enter code here
```